# Maintain static amount of draggable elements html/js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML/JS code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>

        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
            this.style.opacity = '0.4';
        }

        function drop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }

        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Create Left Panel-->
    <div id="leftPanel" class="container-left">
        <!--Create subpanel for each data (submenus) and add initial divs (elements)-->
        <div id="panelEntrada" class="container-left-entrada" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            <div id="draggable1" class="capaEntrada" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="panelOculta" class="container-left-oculta" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            <div id="draggable2" class="capaOculta" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="panelSalida" class="container-left-salida" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            <div id="draggable3" class="capaSalida" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
        </div>

        <!--Divide in 2 sections for each type of activation function-->
        <div id="panelActivacion" class="container-left-activation">
            <div id="panelSigmoidal" class="container-left-activation-left" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
                <div id="draggable4" class="funcSigmoidal" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="panelTanh" class="container-left-activation-right" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                <div id="draggable5" class="funcTanh" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--container right is all the right area(top, right and area de design)-->
    <div class="container-right">
            <!--top just the top part-->
            <div class="container-top"></div>
            <!-- all that's left of the middle part (design y right)-->
            <div class="container-bottom">
                <div id="bottom" class="container-bottom-left" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
                <div class="container-bottom-right"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This with another CSS code generate the following Window

[image]

The little rectangles with no fill on the left are draggable between all the rectangles in the left (green, black, gray, aqua and magenta) and the middle big one (green).
I would like to maintain a static amount (just 1) of each of my rectangles in their original position, but be able to add them to the middle part, somewhat like a drawer where you can drag any amount of objects from the drawer but the original ones are always left there and new ones are added to your design area.

Any ideas on how to do this? I can only use HTML/JS/CSS

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, just change the following line

ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

to

ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));